# How do I get expressjs app with ejs client to download pdf file with no issue?

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, ejs

I am using expressjs framework to download a file from server. The pdf file should download in response to an "a" tag click event on the ejs front-end. When event occurs I am getting an "undefined" text file instead of the expected pdf file. My head is spinning...what could be the issue with my code?

**ejs client html body**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="download-file" data-id="<%= book._id%>">Download Book</a>
```

**ejs client script**

```
            const getFile = document.querySelector("a.download-file");
            getFile.addEventListener("click", () => {
                const endPoint = `/pages/${getFile.dataset.id}`;
                if (confirm(`Confirm PDF download to your computer`)) {
                    fetch(
                        endPoint, 
                        {method: "GET"}
                        )
                    .then((response) => response.blob())
                    .then((res) => {
                        console.log(res)
                        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
                        const link = document.createElement("a");
                        link.href = url;
                        link.setAttribute("download", "Pdf Book");
                        document.body.appendChild(link);
                        link.click();
                    })
                    .catch((err) => console.log("Error:", err));
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            });
```

**back-end route**

```
bookRouter.get("/:id", bookController.downloadSingleBook);
```

**back-end controller**

```
  const downloadSingleBook = (req, res) => {
    let bookID = req.params.id;
    Book.findById(bookID)
        .then((response) => {
            const file = path.resolve(response.bookfile);
            res.download(file);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

Comment: "ejs client script" — Needs to be in a `<script>` not in EJS. Your EJS is going to run on the server and the HTML it generates sent to the client.

Comment: This seems massively complicated. It's a same origin request. Why not use a regular link?

Comment: "I am getting an "undefined" text file" — You need to do some basic debugging. Where does it start to be undefined? Use the Network tab in the browser's developer tools. Look at the response data. Is it a PDF or is it `undefined`? Add logging to the `Book.findById` callback. Is `response.bookfile` the expected value? Is `file` the expected value? is `boodID` the expected value?

Comment: You already have `console.log(res)`. Does that log the expected value? Does it have a `data` property on it?

Comment: You're using `response.blob()` which returns a blob (in a promise) so why do you have `new Blob([res.data])` in an attempt to pull the data out of your blob and then immediately create a new blob with it?

Comment: @Quentin it's wrapped in <script></script>. It's not in ejs.

Comment: You titled it "ejs client script". Please be accurate when describing where you are putting your code.

Comment: @Quentin `new Blob([res.data])` was partly the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Issue has finally been resolved. It was here on the client `new Blob([res.data])` and here on the server `const file = path.resolve(response.bookfile);`

This is how the final updated working code looks:

**ejs client script (wrapped in js script tag)**

```js
const getFile = document.querySelector("a.download-file");

getFile.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const endPoint = `/pages/${getFile.dataset.id}`;
  if (confirm(`Confirm PDF download to your computer`)) {
    fetch(
      endPoint, 
      { method: "GET" }
    )
      .then((response) => response.blob())
      .then((res) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(res);
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", "Pdf Book");
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log("Error:", err));
  } else {
    return;
  }
});
```

**expressjs back-end controller**

```
const downloadSingleBook = (req, res) => {
let bookID = req.params.id;
Book.findById(bookID)
  .then((response) => {
    const file = response.bookfile;
    res.download(file);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })};
```